# Can I make bolts out of dead goblins?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After slaughtering a bunch of goblin invaders, the dwarfs promptly piled up their corpses in my refuse pile.

Fast-forward a few seasons and the corpses decomposed to the point where only their skeletons remain. Being low on ammunition at the moment I decided to put those goblin bones to good use and make bone bolts out of them, like I sometimes do with cows and kittens.

Trouble is, the dwarfs refuse to make bolts because they need "unrotten bone body parts". But I have more than two dozen skeletons outside!

Can I use those bones or not? If that is possible, how can I get the dwarfs to make nice goblin bone bolts, so they can take out the next wave of besiegers with the goblin's own ancestors?

Comment: This is a very horrendous variant of fighting fire with fire...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you butchered the skeletons? Dwarf ethics may prevent the butchering of intelligent enemies, but they have no qualms butchering their bones.

Alternatively, skeletons and partial skeletons *should* "eventually" decompose into stacks of bones. But why wait?

Comment: I remember one fort site that had no iron ore whatsoever. I eventually started referring to sieges as "Goblinite" because my main iron source was melting down captured goblin weapons... :)

Comment: It's things like this that make DF so great.

Comment: What version are you using?  I'm on v0.34.11 and it won't let me butcher goblin partial skeletons, which makes my marksdwarves sad.

Comment: @edsobo At the time this question was asked, v0.31.XX. I'm not sure of the truth now.